# php data include hard coded link

Tags: php

I have a root url for a php site stored in a config file, such as:

```
<?php $site_url="http://www.the-root-url/";   ?>
```

Then I have a slide show which includes images using the data src attribute, like this:

```
$slides = array(
        '  <div data-src="images/front.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
               "quotation"
            </div>
        </div>',
```

I intend to use my include to introduce the images, so its an absolute file-path, something like this `"$site_url/images/front.jpg"`.

I don't know how to hard code the full url: **i.e** `"$site_url/images/front.jpg".`

I have tried various things, `<?php echo $site_url; ?>images/front.jpg , just $site_url`images/front.jpg  as well as `{$site_url`}images/front.jpg`   but none work..can somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: Are you including config file in the second file in which you are trying to use `$site_url` variable?

Comment: Yes I have a navigation in the same file as the 'slideshow' and the include is working, ie <option value="<?php echo $site_url; ?>index.php">HOME</option>.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
$site_url="http://www.the-root-url/";

$slides = array(
    '  <div data-src="'.$site_url.'images/front.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
  "quotation"
        </div>
    </div>',
```

to join the site string with the path-string